# Re-positioning map grid coordinate labels in QGIS layout

Tags: qgis

I've created a map grid in QGIS (3.12) layout. Is there a way/expression to re-position the map grid coordinate labels so they are not overlying the map grid? It would be good to offset them to the side of the grids.

Is there also a way to add a drop shadow to these labels?

This is what the grid and labels currently look like:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with 2 grids.

So the first one is one with just the cross marks.

Then a second one with just the labels. And set a suitable offset for the second grid. Bearing in mind that you will have to create a custom label for the grid as well.

So for me:

Grid 1:

Simple full line grid.

[image]

Grid 2:

Just the annotations, with a 5000 meter offset. I then also need to adjust the "Format" to be "Custom" with a formula of:

```
@grid_number - 5000
```

Otherwise it would be the label with the offset included.

[image]

Combined:

[image]

There is currently no way to add a drop shadow to the text (as of QGIS version 3.10.2-A Coruña).

Comment: That's great - thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

As of about QGIS 3.16, you can do this with one grid. Not sure when drop shadows were added, but these can certainly be done in QGIS 3.34.

To enable labels above the line, set all the **Draw Coordinates** settings to *Inside Frame*, and *Above Tick* (for above the grid line) or *Under Tick* (for below the line):

[image]

To enable the drop shadow, click on Font:

[image]

Select the Background tab (on the right hand end) and then check the *Draw drop shadow* box to turn on drop shadow:

[image]

Final output:

[image]